# Are the comic strips in the Marvel logo relevant to each film?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, credits

In each MCU film, you get the Marvel logo will lots of different comic strips flashing on the screen. Do these strip differ to cater to what each film is about, or are they always the same?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "MCU film"? Do you mean all films with the Marvel logo intro or do you strictly mean the Marvel Studios produced projects?

Comment: I wonder about this too, since it seemed that the pre-Iron Man movies *did* customize to panels to the featured hero(es).  The current movies' logo goes too fast for me to tell (but I think it's deliberately generic now).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Answer: Sometimes.

---

### The Same:

This is the MCU one **(Iron-Man through Iron-Man 3** (excluding the Hulk)) and is also used in such films as the **Blade trilogy,  Spider-man trilogy, Daredevil (2004), X-Men franchise, and Man-Thing.**

And this is the new one introduced with **Thor 2: The Dark World and continues for all current MCU works.**

---

### Different

This is a compilation that shows some variance based on the show. **Specifically The Hulk movies, Electra, Fantastic Four (2005, 2007), Ghost Rider, and Punisher Movies**. Some of them are a variation of the first one (with choice character frames inserted), while others are completely redone with their character / color palette.

*(It also incorrectly shows Thor 2 and Age of Ultron as having the old non-3D logo).*

Comment: This isn't *techincally* true... the Hulk one is green... There's a composite video on YouTube of all of them here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7cYKt8RqY8

Comment: @Catija Okay, that video isn't *fully* correct, as it doesn't have the new 3D version from Thor 2 and onward, but it did have some variances, so I'll include them.

Comment: Did Marvel (or an obsessed fan) ever specify which strips are in the logos? Because the Hulk one that Catija mentioned *does* seem to specifically contain strips from Hulk comics (beyond being green).

Comment: Is this one better: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_ODOzfTR28

Comment: @Walt The Elektra one also seems to have Elektra-featured cells in it.

Comment: @Catija I have updated my answer hopefully separating same from different.

Comment: I think you are missing a closing parentheses after "Iron-Man through Iron-Man 3 (excluding the Hulk)" because it sounds like you are including the blade trilogy, spider-man trilogy and the others in the MCU. At first I got excited and thought the Blade trilogy is part of the MCU and I haven't heard about it.

Comment: @Andrew That I was.